# delete query for oracle table taking a infinite amount of time using python

Tags: database, python-3.x, oracle11g

This is my piece of code:

```
my_dsn_tns= cx_Oracle.makedsn('xyz', 1521, sid = 'SAMPLE')
connection =cx_Oracle.connect(user='username',password='pass', dsn=my_dsn_tns)
cur = connection.cursor()
cur.execute("delete from SPS_CX_ONHAND_QTY")
```

I am using python to delete all the records from a oracle table but this code is not showing any results nor any error. The time I hit run, it just goes in an infinite loop. I have no idea what the problem is all about.

Comment: but seems you are missing in a command what are you deleting

Comment: Why do you think it is looping - there is no loop in what you've shown? If it just isn't responding, I'd guess you have uncommitted changes to the table in another session - that will block the delete until that session commits or rolls back.

Comment: How do I create a new session for this?

Comment: As you are deleting all rows, just a suggestion - if possible, consider **truncating** it instead; should be much faster than deleting.