# deleting all the rows from oracle table using python taking infinite amount of time

Tags: database, python-3.x, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

My piece of code is as follows:

```
my_dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn('xyz', 1521, sid='SAMPLE')
connection = cx_Oracle.connect(user='asdasdasd', password='TIGER', dsn=my_dsn_tns)
cur = connection.cursor()
cur.execute("delete from SPS_CX_ONHAND_QTY")
connection.commit()
```

When I execute the following code, it does not give me any error but at the same time does not do anything. Do I need to make any changes in my code?

Comment: [You've asked this before](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52419971/266304). Have you checked whether there are any uncommitted changes in other sessions which are blocking the delete? [This might be helpful to check](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7502176/266304).

Answer (score 2):

Not python related or the code you have above but generally in SQL, if you are deleting all the rows in a table you can use `truncate table SPS_CX_ONHAND_QTY`.
This would be almost instantaneous.